# How to install netfx-4.7.2-devpack fails with chocolatey

Tags: aws-codebuild, chocolatey

We use AWS codebuild and have the following in our buildspec.yml file to create the build server.

```
pre_build:
    commands:
        - echo Installing Pre-Requisites
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco info netfx-4.6.2-devpack
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y netfx-4.6.2-devpack
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco info netfx-4.7.2-devpack
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y netfx-4.7.2-devpack
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y chocolatey-visualstudio.extension
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y visualstudio-installer
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y visualstudio2019buildtools --version=16.10.2.0
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y visualstudio2019-workload-webbuildtools
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y visualstudio2017-workload-webbuildtools
        - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco upgrade -y python
```

This has been working fine until yesterday.  It started bombing on the netfx-4.7.2-devpack install line.  Unfortunately the guy who knows this stuff is on vacation and I need to get it working again and can't wait for him to get back.  This is what's showing up in the logs.

```
[Container] 2021/09/03 14:00:50 Running command C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco info netfx-4.7.2-devpack
Chocolatey v0.10.15
netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225 [Approved] Downloads cached for licensed users

 Title: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack | Published: 2/26/2019

 Package approved as a trusted package on Feb 26 2019 01:02:36.

 Package testing status: Exempted on Feb 26 2019 01:02:36.

 Number of Downloads: 684002 | Downloads for this version: 345299

 Package url
 Chocolatey Package Source: https://github.com/jberezanski/ChocolateyPackages/tree/master/netfx-4.7.2-devpack

 Package Checksum: 'H/RkhoWtLXMzTpcglI7gfTeqhCU52+/6BCT5Vn3W50leaA9yn0ai17F4oeXZ2gfWemUPrOqE3NKL/SLo87ldwA==' (SHA512)
 Tags: microsoft .net framework 4.7.2 developer target targeting pack multi dotnet netfx admin
 Software Site: https://www.microsoft.com/net/
 Software License: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/cc300389.aspx
 Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx

 Issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues
 Summary: The .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack lets developers build applications that target the .NET Framework 4.7.2.

 Description: The .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack lets developers build applications that target the .NET Framework 4.7.2 by using Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2015 or other IDEs. This is a single package that bundles the .NET Framework 4.7.2, the .NET 4.7.2 Targeting Pack, and the .NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK.
 Release Notes: ##### Software
  [.NET Framework 4.7.2 announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/30/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-2/)
  [.NET Framework 4.7.2 readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/README.md)
  [.NET Framework 4.7.2 changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md)
  ##### Package
  4.7.2.20190225: Implemented workaround for native installer crash under WinRM/DSC (https://github.com/jberezanski/ChocolateyPackages/issues/22).

1 packages found.

[Container] 2021/09/03 14:00:52 Running command C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y netfx-4.7.2-devpack
Chocolatey v0.10.15

Installing the following packages:
netfx-4.7.2-devpack

By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 7%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 20%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 34%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 48%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 62%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 76%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 89%
Progress: Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 4.7.2.20190225... 100%

netfx-4.7.2-devpack v4.7.2.20190225 [Approved]

netfx-4.7.2-devpack package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.

Attempt to get headers for https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/F/3BFB9C35-405D-45DF-BDAF-0EB57D047888/NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe failed.

  The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/F/3BFB9C35-405D-45DF-BDAF-0EB57D047888/NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Downloading netfx-4.7.2-devpack 64 bit
  from 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/F/3BFB9C35-405D-45DF-BDAF-0EB57D047888/NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe'

ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/F/3BFB9C35-405D-45DF-BDAF-0EB57D047888/NDP472-DevPack-ENU.exe'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." 

This package is likely not broken for licensed users - see https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-private-cdn.

The install of netfx-4.7.2-devpack was NOT successful.

Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\netfx-4.7.2-devpack\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.

 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.

 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - netfx-4.7.2-devpack (exited 404) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\netfx-4.7.2-devpack\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.

 See log for details.

[Container] 2021/09/03 14:01:04 Command did not exit successfully C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y netfx-4.7.2-devpack exit status 404

[Container] 2021/09/03 14:01:04 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED

[Container] 2021/09/03 14:01:04 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco install -y netfx-4.7.2-devpack. Reason: exit status 404
```

Any idea how to get this working again?

Answer (score 0):

Use "choco install netfx-4.8-devpack -y" instead of old version

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.